# ReactJS does not connect with NodeJS API using socket.io

Tags: node.js, reactjs, socket.io

I have an issue trying to connect a reactJS app with a nodeJS API using socket.io.

Here's API code :

```
    const httpServer = require('http').createServer();
    const io = require('socket.io')(httpServer);

    httpServer.listen(8080, () => {
      console.log('go to http://localhost:8080');
    });

    io.on('connection', socket => {
        console.log('client connected');
      });
```

And reactapp :

```
    import React from "react";
    import socketIOClient from "socket.io-client";
    const ENDPOINT = "http://localhost:8080";


    function App(){
      const socket=socketIOClient.connect(ENDPOINT);
      return(<p>Hello</p>);
    }
    export default App;
```

As you can see, it is a simple code but still it doesn't work.
The 'client connected' message from the API never shows up.
It looks like the react app can't connect to the port even if it's open or idk.

Comment: check properly in websckets tab

Answer (score 0):

It may happen because of syntax in the react app side. Can you try this one in the function?

```
function App(){
      let socket = io(ENDPOINT, {
        transports: ["websocket"],
      });

      console.log("Connecting...");
      socket.on("connect", () => console.log("Connected!"));
    }
```

or you can define socket outside of the function.